How can I make a widget follow a straight path to another widget's position?
I have a simple code where there are two main Widgets containing different Chips, whenever you tap one Chip, it "teleports" to the other container. I want to animate it so when you tap one chip, instead of teleporting, it actually moves (so you can follow the trace with the eye, like in Duolingo exercises, for example). I'm kinda new in flutter and I cant figure this one out.
I have researched and found out that you can get a widget coordinates, and then I guess I just need to animate one of the Chips moving towards there, but I don't understand how :(
This is my code so you can see what I'm talking about:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyAppState with ChangeNotifier {}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MyAppState(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'FormublocksBeta1',
        theme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepOrange),
        ),
        home: const Formulas(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Formulas extends StatefulWidget {
  const Formulas({super.key});

  @override
  State<Formulas> createState() => _FormulasState();
}

class _FormulasState extends State<Formulas> {
  List<String> draggedWords = [];
  List<String> words = ["I", "love", "Flutter"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                width: 300,
                height: 300,
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surfaceContainer,
                child: Center(
                  child: Wrap(
                    children: draggedWords.map((word) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            words.add(word);
                            draggedWords.remove(word);
                          });
                        },
                        child: Chip(
                          label: Text(word),
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary),
                          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(110),
                            side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: words.map((word) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      words.remove(word);
                      draggedWords.add(word);
                    });
                  },
                  child: Chip(
                    label: Text(word),
                    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary),
                    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(110),
                      side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Thanks in advance.

can you share the design?

@MunsifAli I have edited the post with a link to what I meant :)

You should learn more about animations in the documentation, get a solid initial knowledge:
https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/animations

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
